# List validation to force fields to be conditionally mandatory

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, development, validation-list-items

I have a custom list inside sharepoint on-premises 2013, which have these fields:-

1. Status. drop-down(Open,Closed).
2. Type. drop-down(item,Box).
3. Comment. Multiple line of text (allow pictures and tables).
4. Actions. Multiple line of text (allow pictures and tables).
5. Detailed Description. Multiple line of text (allow pictures and tables).

now i want to set this validation:-

1. if the Status is set to Closed, then the user must enter values inside the Comment.
2. if the Status is set to Closed and the Type = Box, then in-addition to the above case, the user must enter text inside the Actions and Detailed Description fields.

so i am not sure if i can benefit from the list validation to perform the above 2 validations?

Answer (score 0):

List validation settings is not supported to validate value of a multiple-lines of text field.

If you want to validate value of a multiple-lines of text field, you need script to overwrite the PreSaveAction function by applying client-side validation.

Here is a demo for your reference: [Introduction to Client Forms Validation in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/14/introduction-to-client-forms-validation-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below method that i have followed.
You can write a PreSaveAction function and write your validation in the below function. 
Please find the example of the code.

```
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function PreSaveAction(){
   var Status =  $("select[title='Status']").val();
   var Type =   $("select[title='Type']").val();


      if (Status ==="Closed"){
        alert("Please Enter the comments below");
        $("input[title='Comment']").focus();
         return false;
           }    

            if(Status=== "Closed" && Type==="Box")
         {
        alert("Please Enter the details in Comment,Action,Details Description Field 
    ");
      $("input[title='Comment']").focus();
        $("input[title='Actions']").focus();
     $("input[title='Detailed Description']").focus();
     return false;
         }
      return true;
          }
```

Please mark the answer correct if it solved your issue.
Thanks!!!